# Deleted photos in my camera

Tags: restore, camera

I have accidentally deleted some photos from my camera and than found out, that those photos were really precious to my girlfriend.
I tried googling and both windows and linux tools to recover those files but no result.

The problem is, that when I plug in my camera I is mounted to /run/user/jendas/gvfs and mount says:

```
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/jendas/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=jendas)
```

So I can not access my files with the tools I tried cause they always need something like /sda...

Please is there any way around? I don't wanna die :-(

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I do not really think, that path to my camera will be /dev/sda... I checked every location marked as fuseblk in corresponding mount directory and the camera is not there.

Here is what gives mount:

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,discard,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/jendas/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=jendas)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/jendas/Rezervováno systémem type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/jendas/EE2AC63D2AC60317 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb6 on /media/jendas/099218f3-ad22-4022-900f-c39b98049fdf type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb4 on /media/jendas/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /media/jendas/B4AED817AED7D04A type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

My camera is here listed as line, that I have already typed above.

**Final edit:** Finally I have recovered the pictures! So I won't be destroyed by mighty and terrifying feminine look.
I the end I solve the problem by removing the memory card from camera and plugging it into another notebook with working memory card reader. Than I followed the standard procedure. 
I wonder, that my problems were probably caused by the camera it self and its firmware. I think that it handles the usb connection in some non-standard and creepy way so the kernel can't it properly identify as external removable drive.

So thank you all anyway and have a good day.

PS: I will accept the original answer posted lower because it helped me solve at least part of the problem :-)

Comment: you should get another line, something like that: `/dev/sdb1 on /media/mike/244E31704E313C3C type fuseblk`

Comment: `/dev/sdx` would be a phisical device name, regardless of where its partitions are mounted. Sounds like you just need a decent Testdisk tutorial, so how about [this one](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT)?

Comment: Symin - nope, there are just my regular drivers of type fuseblk...
@mikewhatever - I have tried  dd if=/dev/sdx of=my_card.img bs=512 but result: dd: opening ‘/dev/sdx’: No such file or directory

Comment: if the camera is mounted as a gvfs partition it should be part of the /dev where it is mounted on. photorec should be able to catch it, give it a try following the directions below and selecting the /dev where the directory is mounted. Can you remove the memory from the camera and place it into a card reader or soemthing?

Comment: Well I tried photorec but it did not found it :-/ And yes, removing the card a putting it into built-in card reader helped, but I had to place it into another notebook, because my has probably some driver issue. But thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all it is crucial that **you do not write anything on the memory card until you recovered the deleted images**.

Your best bet is [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). It is part of the `testdisk` package. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Then run photorec as super user

```
sudo photorec
```

You'll be presented with the list of connected devices, including your hard drives. Select the memory card (it will probably be something like /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc but check it carefully). Follow the on screen instructions.

Another alternative is `recoverjpeg` that is specifically tailored for JPEG recovery.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install recoverjpeg
```

Open "Disks" (you find it in your applications). You'll find the list of connected devices. Select the memory card. On the right hand you'll find the details of the device included where it is mapped (eg: `/deb/sdb1`)

Then you can try with recoverjpeg like so:

```
sudo recoverjpeg /dev/sdb1
```

**IMPORTANT: replace `sdb1` with your actual device!**

You'll find the recovered pictures in your home directory.

Also have a look at this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery